# Magento 2 remove billing phone

Tags: checkout, magento-2.1

How can I remove the billing phone number from checkout, or at least make it not required?

I've looked everywhere and can't find any references to the form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After facing the same problem, i found [a thread on the official git](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1691). Dated from August 2015...

And someone posted [a proper solution](https://github.com/zsoerenm/magento2-optionaltelephone)

Incredible complexity for just doing that...

Answer (score 12):

I'm not sure about previous versions but in **Magento 2.2** you can go to

> Store > Configuration > CUSTOMERS > Customer Configuration

Then go to the **Name** and **Address** Options tab on the right and look for Show **Telephone** and select your option. **(No) (Optional) (Required)**

It's set to Required by default.

Comment: Yep, this was added in 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it not required for only billing address by run bellow query to database.

> update eav_attribute set is_required=0 where
>   attribute_code='telephone';

Comment: This is to remove the shipping field not the billing field.

Comment: I'd need to add this to checkout_index_index.xml? Under what node path?

Comment: You can check my updated answer for telephone number make it not required only for billing address.

Comment: @William Have you run above query ?

Comment: This is a false/very partial answer, and obviously, has not been tested. The check for telephone is directly in _Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress_ . _Magento\Customer\Model\Address_ and _Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address_ are extending this class. But the the joke, is that if you rewrite that, another injection will not work, (_Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\TotalsCollector_ for example) because waiting for original class. I'm currently looking into it to make it the cleanest way possible...